# using both 1.1, 1.2,... and (a) (b) in a list

Tags: lists, enumerate

I'm very much a beginner in latex, and I would like to make the following list:

> 1. step 1
>
>    1.1 substep 1.1
>
>    1.2 substep 1.2
>
>    (a) option a
>
>    (b) option b
>
>    some text here
> 2. step 2

is that possible?

my current code is

```
\documentclass[aps,pre,reprint,superscriptaddress,amssymb,floatfix,showpacs]{revtex4-1}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{amsfonts}

\usepackage{verbatim}

\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}

\item step 1

\item substep 1.1 

\item substep 1.2 

\begin{enumerate}

\item option a of step 1.2

\item option b of step 1.2

\end{enumerate}

some text here

\item step 2

\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

So you can see my problem.

Is what I am envisioning possible?

I am grateful for you help!

Natali

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. If you mean by (a) and (b) that those are on higher level of nesting than 1.2 this is possible, otherwise difficult and not recommended

Answer (score 4):

Here's an option using `enumitem` (assuming nesting, left your two-column-layout).

[image: enumitem]

```
\documentclass[aps,pre,reprint,superscriptaddress,amssymb,floatfix,showpacs]{revtex4-1}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{array}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\item step 1\begin{enumerate}[label=\theenumi.\arabic*]
\item substep 1.1 
\item substep 1.2 
\begin{enumerate}[label=(\alph*)]
\item option a of step 1.2
\item option b of step 1.2
\end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
some text here
\begin{enumerate}[resume]
\item step 2
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @natali Please consider accepting one of the answers (that helped you most) by clicking the green button at the left. This also marks the question as solved.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution that doesn't require the loading of any additional packages.

[image]

```
\documentclass[aps,pre,reprint,superscriptaddress,
               amssymb,floatfix,showpacs]{revtex4-1}

\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,verbatim,array,lipsum}

\renewcommand\theenumii{\theenumi.\arabic{enumii}}
\renewcommand\labelenumii{\theenumii}
\renewcommand\theenumiii{\alph{enumiii}}
\renewcommand\labelenumiii{(\theenumiii)}
% optional (if you need to create cross-references)
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\p@enumii{}
\renewcommand\p@enumiii{\theenumii.}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\item step 1 \label{item:a}

\begin{enumerate}
\item substep 1.1  
\item substep 1.2 \label{item:b}

\begin{enumerate}
\item option a of step 1.2 \label{item:c}
\item option b of step 1.2
\end{enumerate}
some text here
\end{enumerate}
\item step 2
\end{enumerate}

Cross-references to items \ref{item:a}, \ref{item:b}, and \ref{item:c}.

\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here in a small improvement, to have the same margins as in the question:

```
\documentclass[aps,pre,reprint,superscriptaddress,amssymb,floatfix,showpacs]{revtex4-1}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{lipsum, calc}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[enumerate]{wide}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[leftmargin=*]
  \item step 1\begin{enumerate}[wide =0pt, label=\theenumi.\arabic*, leftmargin =*]
          \item substep 1.1
          \item substep 1.2
                \begin{enumerate}[label=(\alph*), wide =\dimexpr-\leftmarginii+\labelsep, leftmargin=0pt, labelsep =*]
                  \item option a of step 1.2. Some text. Some more text. Some more text. Some more text. Some more text.
                  \item option b of step 1.2
                \end{enumerate}
        \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
some text here
\begin{enumerate}[resume]
  \item step 2
\end{enumerate}
\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

[image]