# Page break within table rows

Tags: page-breaking, longtable

I have a longtable that has paragraphs in each cell in the second column. My problem is that when a page ends, it can break only at the end of a row. This often leaves large blank space at the end of some pages, which I have to adjust manually. Was wondering if there is some way I can tell LaTeX to break the page within a row, where needed, so that I won't have to do it manually. Or, maybe some other way of doing it. A minimal example that I could create is as follows:

```
\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}{lp{0.9\textwidth}}
1 & \lipsum[1].\\
2. &\lipsum[2].\\
3. &\lipsum[3].\\
4. &\lipsum[4].\\
5 & \lipsum[5].\\
6. &\lipsum[6].\\
7. &\lipsum[7].\\
8. &\lipsum[8].\\
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

Here you can see some blank space at the end of the first page. In my work this space sometimes becomes much bigger.

Comment: pagebreaks are only possible between row, not within them. See also: [Longtable: page breaks within row possible?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/78578/134144)

Comment: Your current example looks a bit like the longtable could easily be replaced by an `enumerate`list. Maybe this is an alternative that works for you.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't think of it because the numbers are actually like 1.1, 1.2... 2.1, 2.2 and so on. Here the first digit represents the section. I tried the suggestion given here: [https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/380702/using-both-1-1-1-2-and-a-b-in-a-list], but then, I have to give an item at the beginning from which the first part of the number comes, without which LaTeX throws up an error. If I do that by making the section heading an \item, the first part of the number also becomes Large bold as the heading has to be in that type face. But for this, enumerate works fine here.

Comment: I think, a solution could be if I could define enumi as something like 1.\arabic*, which then I could manually change in each section to 2.\arabic*, 3.\arabic* and so on. But I don't see a way to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the help of the `enumitem` package you can easily and automatically add the number of the current section to the actual item number:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setenumerate[1]{label=\thesection.\arabic*.}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\section{first section header}

\begin{enumerate}
\item \lipsum[1]
\item \lipsum[2]
\item \lipsum[3]
\item \lipsum[4]
\item \lipsum[5]
\end{enumerate}

\section{second section header}

\begin{enumerate}
\item \lipsum[1]
\item \lipsum[2]
\item \lipsum[3]
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks. This should have been good enough, but in my particular case, I found that description is a better option, with the numbers added manually. The matter is a bit too complex to explain in a comment here.